# R List & Data Frame Formatting

Tags: r, list, dataframe

So I have a list of lists as an .rda file. There are 51 elements in the list, corresponding to the state abbreviations, i.e. "ca," "fl," etc.  Each state has a state.in and state.out element.  So for instance, there is a long list of migration data that can be accessed as `data_9495$ca$state.in` and another named `data_9495$ca$state.out`.  In order to make this giant data file consistent with some other stuff, I need to change a few values in both the state.in and state.out elements of every state in the data file.  The data file is called `data_9495`, and I need the elements of the list to actually be changed so I can resave the datafile and use it later.  What I have so far is:

```
datafile<-"data_9495"
datafile<-gsub("\\.rda$","",datafile)
loaded_data <- load(paste("/Users/blah/blah/Listed     Data/", datafile, ".rda", sep=""))
d<-get(loaded_data[1])
require("UScensus2010")
data(countyfips)
states<-unique(countyfips[,4])
for(k in 1:length(states)){
    state<-states[k]
    print(k)
state.in<-as.data.frame(d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][1])
state.out<-as.data.frame(d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][2])


{for(j in 1:dim(state.in)[1])
{
    if(state.in[j,3]=="63"&&state.in[j,4]=="050")
        {state.in[j,3]<-state.in[j,1]
        state.in[j,4]<-state.in[j,2]}

}
for(i in 1:dim(state.out)[1])
{
    if(state.out[i,3]=="63"&& state.out[i,4]=="050")
        {state.out[i,3]<-state.out[i,1]
        state.out[i,4]<-state.out[i,2]}
}
assign(d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][1],state.in)
assign(d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][2],state.out)
}}
```

The .rda file can be downloaded at: (click the underlined thing that says "data 9495.rda" at the top)
http://speedy.sh/vr7JQ/data-9495.rda

The code as it is will "run" but it does not appear to actually be changing the values that I need changed.  Note that the column classes are indeed characters, which is why there are quotations in my for-loop if-statements.  Why isn't this changing the data, and how can I make it change it?

Comment: Can you give a very specific example of a value exists when the data is loaded that you believe should be changed and what you think it should be changed to before the data is saved again?

Comment: It is supposed to iterate through the rows.  If the 3rd column is "63" and the 4th column of the same row is "050", then the 3rd column should be changed to the number (technically a character) that is in the 1st column (it will be something like "04") and the 4th column should be changed to the number (again, technically a character) that is in the 2nd column, which will be something like "035").  Note that this is all in the same row.

Comment: So which specific row/state in the data do you expect to change? Where are you looking to see that it doesn't work?

Comment: I need to change the 3rd and 4th column (conditionally) of both state.in and state.out for each state.  After I run the code above I just print out the .rda file, i.e. data_9495$ca$state.in and it does not appear to have changed.  I printed out state.in and state.out and it seems to have changed there, but not in the original datafile.  I think that means I have to somehow assign it back to the data_9495 object, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I tried assigning it with the assign() function but I can't get that to work.

Comment: Well, you never `save()` back to the data file. The `load()` commands loads the data into memory, but after that it doesn't touch the file on disc unless you specifically call `save()`. Assign doesn't have anything to do with the `rda` file

Comment: The problem isn't so much that it isn't changing it, it's that it changes state.in, which is in a sense separated from, say, data_9495$ca$state.in.  I can't get the new, revised state.in that the function modifies to replace the data_9495$ca$state.in.  I.e., after I run the function, and print out data_9495$ca$state.in, it will be the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `assign` is not necessary and is of the wrong syntax anyway (the second argument should be a character vector.

Try using this syntax instead

```
for(k in 1:length(states)){
    state<-states[k]
    print(k)
    state.in <- d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][["state.in"]]
    state.out <- d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][["state.out"]]

    ...

    d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][["state.in"]] <- state.in
    d[[which(names(d)==tolower(state))]][["state.out"]] <- state.out
}}
```